# WPF Running a command on a windows form

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

I have a WPF Project to which i've added a Windows Form.

The windows form has a method `runme()`. But I'd like to call it from the WPF form.

Currently I've used

```
Dim wpfForm as new wpfForm
wpfForm.Show()
```

to display the the WPF form from a Windows form.

I'm not sure how to send a command back though.

I've tried:

```
Me.parent.runme()
```

But this gives me errors

Comment: Is it possible to add a constructor parameter to your wpfForm? You can use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to provide a reference back to the parent. You could even use an interface, rather than forcing your WPF Form to accept a WinForm Form as the parameter.

Comment: The error I get is `Value of type 'System.Windows.Window' cannot be converted to 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually what worked was to create an interface as suggested by Cyborgx37

```
Interface ILogOut
    Sub DoIt()
End Interface

Class WinFormWindow : Implements ILogOut
    Public Sub DoIt() Implements ILogOut.DoIt
        MsgBox("Message Received!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can then use the ILogOut interface to send a message to the Windows forms window from a WPF window

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think of to do what you are wanting is to create a Custom Constructor for your Winform and pass the reference to the Wpf Window to it. [There appears to be no easy way](http://www.codingtiger.com/questions/wpf/How-to-use-a-FolderBrowserDialog-from-a-WPF-application.html) to assign a WPF Window as an Owner/Parent of a Winforms Window.

**Winforms Form**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim myParent As System.Windows.Window
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(parent As System.Windows.Window)
        myParent = parent
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CType(myParent, MainWindow).runMe()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Wpf Form**

```
Class MainWindow 
    Dim winForm As Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        winForm = New Form1(Me)
        winForm.Show()
    End Sub
    Public Sub runMe()
        Me.Background = Brushes.Red
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This will produce the same error as before, on CType(..).. `Value of type 'System.Windows.Window' cannot be converted to 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow'.`'

Comment: As well as `'WpfApplication1.Main' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Window'` while instantiating the WPF Window

Comment: @Akshat This worked with no errors for me. Make sure that you use the Name of your WPF Windows Class. Also it is a bit confusing are you creating the Winforms window from your Wpf Window, or creating a Wpf Window from your Winforms Window. If the the later there are methods that will work.